# android - show Dialog styled activity over locked screen without unlocking

Tags: android, popup, themes, popupwindow, android-dialog

I am showing a popup screen when the screen is locked when some event happens.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Problem is - after a lot of frustration I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003568/android-galaxy-s4-activity-that-is-visible-over-lock-screen), saying that this doesn't work when the `activity` is using a `Theme.Dialog`.

I want my activity to **not** be full screen, its suppose to be more or less like a sms popup notification. how can I do that without the `Theme.Dialog` Theme?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this wraped everything in the window that pops up for me:

Key part of code is 'WRAP_CONTENT':

```
    WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    View mView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dialogue_page, null);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```