# finish background activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-background

I launch a new activity "ActivityB" when keypad is locked.(ActivityA has been backgrounded before the keypad is locked).
ActivityB times out after 30 secs and supposed to close itself, so I called finish after 30 secs, though is not visible, after I unlock I see 2 seperate apps/activities in background.
So I used Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT broadcastreceiver to finish activityB, still it doesnt work.

Manifest.xml

```
  <receiver
            android:name="com.example.reciever.UnlockReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

UnlockReceiver:
public class UnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        if (ActivityB.b != null) {
            ActivityB.b .finish();
        }
}
```

}

ActivityB:

```
private Activity b;
onCreate() {
b= this;
}
```

ActivityB is started as we receive push:

```
Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
                pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

I see the onReceive called fine when I unlock the device, but it doesn't finsih ActivityB in the background. Hence I see 2 of the same apps in background

Answer (score 0):

you may have an intent in activity a which is creating the activity b;

Comment: I called finish after 30 secs, it doesnt seem to work. ActivityB is started based on pushnotification, I used CLEAR TASK, which dosnt seem to clear ActivityA

Comment: try to implement that clear task in background service

Comment: looked like setting android:launchMode="singleTop" fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed after I set the below property in manifest file
android:launchMode="singleTop"